# Scraping: how to reformat data collection and output csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code is meant to loop through all of the results pages, and then loop through the results table on each of the pages and scrape all the data from the table as well as some information stored outside of the table.

Currently, my code will just scrape the first name in each table and basically use that as the organizing key. I need for the code to scrape all the information from the table, each name and associated information from each row, and then relate back to each row that has been scraped the general information that applies to all candidates in the table.

For example, see [this page](http://www.elections.ca/WPAPPS/WPR/EN/NC/Details?province=-1&distyear=2013&district=-1&party=-1&selectedid=8561). Currently, my output looks like this:

```
Brian Benoit,25-Jun-16,Conservative,12-May-16,25-Jun-16,Medicine Hat--Cardston--Warner,b'Medicine Hat--Cardston--Warner',Nikolai Punko
```

It should look like this instead:

```
Brian Benoit,25-Jun-16,Conservative,12-May-16,25-Jun-16,Medicine Hat--Cardston--Warner,b'Medicine Hat--Cardston--Warner',Nikolai Punko
Paul Hinman,25-Jun-16,Conservative,12-May-16,25-Jun-16,Medicine Hat--Cardston--Warner,b'Welling, Alberta',Robert B. Barfuss
Michael Jones,25-Jun-16,Conservative,12-May-16,25-Jun-16,Medicine Hat--Cardston--Warner,b'Raymond, Alberta',Dawn M. Hamon
```

And so on, for all six contestants in that race.

My questions are:

(1) How do I rewrite my code to scrape all the data from each row of each table and add to each row the data from the page that is shared by all entries in the table? (ie, achieve the above output)

(1a) How can I get an output of some kind for the `elected/1` category? Currently the output is empty.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import csv


url = "http://www.elections.ca/WPAPPS/WPR/EN/NC?province=-1&distyear=2013&district=-1&party=-1&pageno={}&totalpages=55&totalcount=1368&secondaryaction=prev25"

with open('scrapeOutput2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for i in range(1, 56):
        print(i)
        r  = requests.get(url.format(i))
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
        links = []

        for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('selectedid=')):
            links.append("http://www.elections.ca" + link.get('href'))

        for link in links:
            r  = requests.get(link)
            data = r.text
            cat = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
            header = cat.find_all('span')
            tables = cat.find_all("table")[0].find_all("td")        

            row = [
                #"name": 
                re.sub("[\n\r/]", "", cat.find_all("table")[0].find_all("td", headers="name/1")[0].contents[0]).strip(),
                #"date": 
                header[2].contents[0],
                #"party": 
                re.sub("[\n\r/]", "", cat.find("legend").contents[2]).strip(),
                #"start_date": 
                header[3].contents[0],
                #"end_date": 
                header[5].contents[0],
                #"electoral district": 
                re.sub("[\n\r/]", "", cat.find_all('div', class_="group")[2].contents[2]).strip(),
                #"registered association": 
                re.sub("[\n\r/]", "", cat.find_all('div', class_="group")[2].contents[2]).strip().encode('latin-1'),
                #"elected": 
                re.sub("[\n\r/]", "", cat.find_all("table")[0].find_all("td", headers="elected/1")[0].contents[0]).strip(),
                #"address": 
                re.sub("[\n\r/]", "", cat.find_all("table")[0].find_all("td", headers="address/1")[0].contents[0]).strip(),
                #"financial_agent": 
                re.sub("[\n\r/]", "", cat.find_all("table")[0].find_all("td", headers="fa/1")[0].contents[0]).strip()]


            csv_output.writerow(row)
```